# Inconsistency in ant command - CentOS 6.3

Tags: java, ant

I'm in CentOS 6.3 and I'm attempting to recompile a .java file using the ***ant*** command however I'm getting these two results.

When I run ***ant***:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher. Program will exit.
```

When I run ***sudo ant***:

```
    Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute java
```

When I run ***echo $JAVA_HOME***:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk/
```

Before anyone suggests that I should be using the JRE instead of the JDK, I just need to mention that my installation manual for the software I'm running - OpenGTS - specifically requests the JDK. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the ant version?

Answer (score 0):

ant is script to launch a java program. It appears that script could not figure out a value for ANT_HOME.  On linux the script tries to load /etc/ant.conf which reset the ANT_HOME.  Your symptoms does not match, but it is worth checking.

[Quote from site](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html)

> The cause of this is that there is an old version of ant somewhere in
>   the class path or configuration.
>
> A version of this problem may be seen on some linux systems. Some
>   linux systems (Fedora Core 2 for example), comes with a version of ant
>   pre-installed. There is a configuration file called /etc/ant.conf
>   which if present, the ant shell script will 'dot' include. On Fedora
>   Core 2, the /etc/ant.conf file resets the ANT_HOME environment
>   variable to /usr/share/ant. This causes the problem that an old
>   version of ant (1.5.x in this cause) will be used with a new version
>   of the ant script file.
>
> One can check if this is the case by doing ant --noconfig -version.